# python: difference b/w multiple-ifs and if-elif-else in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am new to Python and I have a question about using if statements inside while loop:

the code is for writing a number-guessing game till the number you entered matches the random integer generated.

the sample code is written as follows:

```
import random
answer=int(random.uniform(1,10))
number=int(input("guess:"))
if number==answer:
    print("correct!")
while(number!=answer):
    if number > answer:
        print("smaller!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    if number < answer:
        print("bigger!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    if number == answer:
        print("bingo!!")
        break
```

and the result I got was:

> guess: 5 smaller! guess again 3 bigger! guess again 4 bingo!!

but when I used **if-elif-elif** or **if-elif-else** inside the while loop instead of the multiple if's, in the case of *first guess was wrong and subsequent guess(es) were correct*, the last **bingo!!** was not shown, for example:

```
import random
answer=int(random.uniform(1,10))
number=int(input("guess:"))
if number==answer:
    print("correct!")
while(number!=answer):
    if number > answer:
        print("smaller!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    elif number < answer:
        print("bigger!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    elif number == answer:
        print("bingo!!")
        break
```

the results became:

> guess: 5 smaller! guess again 3

as shown, after last correct guess, the code just stopped, and "bingo!!" was not displayed.

Can anyone help me understand why this difference occurred when using multiple if's and if-elif-else/elif inside while loop? 
Thank you very much!

**added: I realized my question eventually is, every time after I enter a new value for `number`, from where in the code it will be run again with the new `number`, and how is this different when I used multiple if's or if-elif-else.**

Comment: you cannot use `while(number!=answer):` and expect to test `number == answer` inside you loop

Comment: I realized that, but in the first case with multiple if's, the result worked as what I expected (i.e. the bingo showed up) and i am wondering why that is the case....

Comment: The issue here has **nothing to do with** the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, "elif" (short for "else if") only executes if the prior "if" (or "elif") case didn't execute. If you have a series of "if" statements (rather than "if" followed by a series of "elif" statements), all the conditions in the former will be evaluated (and for any case where the condition evaluates to something truthy, the body of the corresponding "if" will be evaluated, too); by contrast, once a truthy case is found in the "if"..."elif" chain, no additional conditionals in the chain will be considered.

When using it in a loop (or anywhere, for that matter), you need to consider your intended behavior. A good habit to get into as a programmer is to ask yourself, "how could this go wrong?". And, as a good way of guessing that, consider "is it possible for both cases to be true? should both of these cases be executed if both situations match?". Note, also, that in the loop, you can get the same effect of "if ... elif" with a sequences of "if" by adding an explicit "continue" statement to get back to skip to the next iteration of the loop without evaluating the remaining "if" (or other) statements that remain.

Answer (score 1):

This behaves different

```
if condition1: -> checks
    do1 -> executes if condition1 is true
if condition2: -> checks too in any case!!
    do2 -> executes if condition2 is true
```

than this

```
if condition1: -> checks
    do1 -> executes if condition1 is true
elif condition2: -> checks only if condition1 is false!!
    do2 -> executes if condition1 is false and condition2 is true!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following (first program):

1. You guess the wrong number (let's say `8` instead of `5`) the first time.
2. The `while` loop is entered because `number!=answer`
3. You get the `"smaller!"` message, are prompted to guess again. Now you enter `5`.
4. The `if number==answer:` test is done within the same loop. Since it's now `True`, `"bingo!!"` is displayed.
5. The `while` condition is tested, and since now your answer is correct, the loop will not be entered again.
6. The program exits.

Now the second program:

1. You guess the wrong number (let's say `8` instead of `5`) the first time.
2. The `while` loop is entered because `number!=answer`
3. You get the `"smaller!"` message, are prompted to guess again. Now you enter `5`.
4. The `elif number==answer:` test is *not* done because the previous `if` clause already succeeded. No message is displayed.
5. The `while` condition is tested, and since now your answer is correct, the loop will not be entered again.
6. The program exits.

Comment: So in first case, is it true that no matter how many time i guessed and entered the new value for `number`, the if statements are checked under the same while loop, which is the first while loop it entered after the very first guess went wrong?

Comment: I think what I don't get is, when I enter a new value for `number`, from where in the code it will run again? say in the first case, guessed 8 instead of 5, so in the while loop, it checked the **first if**, condition matched so prompted a new value for `number`, then i guessed 5. with this new number, is it that, *since they are in the same level of indentation*, it will first go to the **second if**, found not matching, move to the **third if**, found match and execute, then it moves up a level back to while loop condition and exit?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple.

In your first example (if's node) you are using a if after if, so, when you ask the guess for a number, you will check the next if.

For example:

From this code:

```
while(number!=answer):
    if number > answer:
        print("smaller!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    if number < answer:
        print("bigger!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    if number == answer:
        print("bingo!!")
        break
```

If your number is bigger (Second if) and you type the correct one, you will check it in the third if. So the message will be printed.

In the other hand, we have the second example with the if/elif/else.

```
while(number!=answer):
    if number > answer:
        print("smaller!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    elif number < answer:
        print("bigger!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    elif number == answer:
        print("bingo!!")
        break
```

If we have the example in case number 1, and our guess say a bigger number, it will not check the third condition, because it's a condition of the first if. Code will go to while again, and it will not continue in case of "bingo".

Try this and you will see that code is the same. Try to use if/elif/else more than an if tree, because is the correct way to check things in python.

```
import random
number=-1
answer=int(random.uniform(1,10))
while(number!=answer):
    number=int(input("guess:"))
    if number > answer:
        print("smaller!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    elif number < answer:
        print("bigger!")
        number=int(input("guess again"))
    elif number == answer:
        print("bingo!!")
        break
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, in first case, no matter how many time i guessed and entered the new value of "number", the if statements are checked under the same while loop, which is the first while loop I entered after the very first guess went wrong. And every time a new number is entered, it will check all three if's from top to bottom and enter the if that satisfies?

Comment: While in the second case, every time a new "number" is entered, the while condition will be checked? if still number!=answer, it does what is inside the if or the first elif based on the condition, but if number==answer, the condition for executing while loop is not longer TRUE thus exits the loop directly?

Comment: another question for the first case: say answer = 5, and first time i guessed number = 8, then it will meet the *first* if and do what's inside the first if condition. then say I guessed number = 5, with this new number, how all the if conditions are checked before it reaches the last if condition? will it start from the first if condition again? or it will start from where it left off and check the second if condition first?

Comment: For the first question, yes, it is. But it will check the if's behind the if entered. I mean, if the condition checked is the second, only the third will be checked with the new value. The second question is correct. When the while loop is not true, it will be out. You could have a print with 'Bingo' out of while true, because the only way to exit the while true is an except (code not continue) or while true exit.

Comment: For the last question: All if's are checked, but it will only access when de condition is true. The last if is 'Bingo', so it will be checked at the last time. For this reason, you will always print Bingo if your number is the correct. You could try, as an example, the same code but with the "bingo" if in the first place, you will see the result is the same as the example number 2.